# How to fix my C# click method?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, syntax-error

I am using a list in class Register:

[image]

Comment: Please enter any code you have a question about as text here. Also your title should describe the problem, not just the fact that you have a problem.

Comment: provide code and more detail

Comment: You'd have to be a little more specific as to what's failing where; the image would be better directly in your question, rather than remoted away.

Comment: Take the errors one at a time. Look at the definition for the first err msg and determine what argument you're passing that doesn't fit.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the image your property `O` is a list of type `List<Order>` but the three items you are adding are of type `Shop`.

So either `O` needs to become a `List<Shop>` or the `Order1, Order2, Order3` variables need to be type `Order`.